# "* is not allowed by the schema"

Tags: meteor, telescope

I'm rather new to Telescope and Meteor.

I've added a custom field as such:

```
Users.addField({
    fieldName: 'apiToken',
    fieldSchema: {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            group: 'API Token',
            label: 'Token'
        },
        optional: true,
        editableBy: ["member", "manager", "admin"]
    }
});
```

I got the field to appear in the User settings,
but whenever I try to enter something and submit,
it gives me the error "`apiToken is not allowed by the schema`".

I'm not sure if this is a Telescope or Meteor issue.

Do I need to edit the schema in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to [Sacha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649299/sacha).

When adding a new field to Telescope, you must declare it on both the client and server.

**package.js**

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {
    // client
    api.addFiles([
        "strawberry_fields.js"
    ], "client");

    // server
    api.addFiles([
        "strawberry_fields.js"
    ], "server");
}
```

**strawberry_fields.js**

```
Users.addField({
    fieldName: 'Likes strawberries',
    fieldSchema: {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            group: 'Strawberries',
            label: 'Strawberries'
        },
        optional: true,
        editableBy: ["member", "manager", "admin"]
    }
});
```